# python for loop assignment of variable

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, assign

I am trying to assign the value of the variable c in this for loop.

The code without the loop works fine however, when I add the loop the .assign(c=lambda x:eval(b)) portion is not assigning the value of the variable c, instead it is creating a field named 'c'.

```
 for b,c in list(zip(file.transform,file.target_field)):


        df=df.set_index(['ID','Value'])    
        df = (df.unstack(0).T
            .assign(c=lambda x:eval(b))
            .stack()
            .unstack(0)).reset_index()
```

I tried updating the code to:

```
.assign(eval(c)=lambda x:eval(b))
```

but I get an error 'keyword cant be an expression'

Comment: wait, why is `df=df.set_index(['ID','Value'])` in the loop ? If you set the index in the first time of the loop it will raise an error at the second time because they already are index

Comment: its being unstacked in the second line of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are giving `c` as a keyword argument to `assign`.

You are on the right track by trying `eval(c)`, and a better way to do it would be to create a dictionary with your kwargs, like this:

```py
 for b,c in list(zip(file.transform,file.target_field)):
        # `c` will be evaluated to its value here
        args = {c: lambda x:eval(b)}
        df=df.set_index(['ID','Value'])    
        df = (df.unstack(0).T
            .assign(**args)
            .stack()
            .unstack(0)).reset_index()
```